# .isin() with a column from a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I query a table using `isin()` with another dataframe? For example there is this dataframe, `df1`:

```
| id      | rank |
|---------|------|
| SE34SER | 1    |
| SEF3445 | 2    |
| 5W4G4F  | 3    |
```

I want to query a table where a column in the table `isin(df1.id)`. I tried doing so like this:

```
t = (
    spark.table('mytable')
    .where(sf.col('id').isin(df1.id))
    .select('*')
).show()
```

However it errors:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't pass another dataframe's column to isin() method. You can get all the values of that column in a list and pass list to isin() method but this is not a better approach.

You can do inner join between those 2 dataframes.

```
df2 = spark.table('mytable')
df2.join(df1.select('id'),df1.id == df2.id, 'inner')
```

Comment: is it possible to do with a column from the same dataframe?